# FCM Click Event With Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using Xamarin forms -pcl v 2.3.4.267 -Plugin.FirebasePushNotification v 1.04- and prism MVVM library- Debug on Android Device.

I implemented the FCM depending on this Documentation https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/README.md
and i send notification successfully to the App what i am stuck with is

how to open a specific page when user clicks the notification and the chosen page will be opened according to the notification type e.g.(when user clicks notification about accepting offers the offers pages will be opened ,when user clicks Alarm Notification the alarm Page will be opened ).

I tried to Implement IPushNotificationHandler in App.cs class but onopened method never be hit.

Besides OnNotificationOpened never called even if i open the notification .

**UPDATE**

in App.cs i subscribed a topic

```
     public App(Prism.DryIoc.IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer)
    {
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("general");
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s,p) =>
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN : {p.Token}");
        };
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s,p) =>
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");

        };


        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
        {

           // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Opened");
            foreach (var data in p.Data)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Identifier))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"ActionId: {p.Identifier}");
            }

        };
```

In mainapplication i added

```
     #if DEBUG
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,
                      new NotificationUserCategory[]
                      {
                new NotificationUserCategory("message",new List<NotificationUserAction> {
                    new NotificationUserAction("Reply","Reply", NotificationActionType.Default),
                    new NotificationUserAction("Forward","Forward", NotificationActionType.Foreground)

                }),
                new NotificationUserCategory("request",new List<NotificationUserAction> {
                new NotificationUserAction("Accept","Accept", NotificationActionType.Default, "check"),
                new NotificationUserAction("Reject","Reject", NotificationActionType.Default, "cancel")
                })
                      }, true);
     #else
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,
            new NotificationUserCategory[]
            {
                new NotificationUserCategory("message",new 
        List<NotificationUserAction> {
                    new NotificationUserAction("Reply","Reply", 
       NotificationActionType.Foreground),
                    new NotificationUserAction("Forward","Forward", 
        NotificationActionType.Foreground)

                }),
                new NotificationUserCategory("request",new List<NotificationUserAction> {
                new NotificationUserAction("Accept","Accept", NotificationActionType.Default, "check"),
                new NotificationUserAction("Reject","Reject", NotificationActionType.Default, "cancel")
                })
            }, false);
        #endif
```

Then i sent data message, i received the Notification and after opening the notification the

```
     CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened
```

is hit but never go through its code block.

Comment: I think your activity is not the main launcher activity. 
Have you declare the FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(Intent) on your activity with MainLauncher = true ?

Comment: exactly , the MainLauncher=false cause the main one was the splash activity.